# Subversive: Compare with Revision operation failed

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I get the following error message in eclipse (Mars) when trying to Compare With -> Base from Working Copy, using the Subversive plugin and the SVNKit connector:

```
SVN: '0x00400103: Compare with Revision' operation finished with error: svn: E195000: A path under version control is needed for this operation
svn: E195000: A path under version control is needed for this operation
```

My SVN password changed recently, and IIRC there was some subversion related updates that were installed recently as part of a periodic Eclipse plugin update. I'm not sure if either is related.

I've gone into the SVN Repository Exploring view, and cleared my Location Properties, as I've seen suggested in other password change threads, which got me access to the repository again, but doesn't fix this issue. I've also tried deleting my %AppData%/Roaming/Subversion/auth/svn.simple/* cached config data to no avail.

Anyone have any ideas?

*Edit - I updated my SVN Connector to use Native JavaHL 1.8.14. Sounds like I needed JavaHL for Windows 7 x64. Comparing with Base from Working Copy still doesn't work, but Compare With -> Latest from Repository does work.

Comment: i am also getting the same exception when comparing with the local copy.

Comment: Me too - after Upgrading Eclipse "Mars" to "Mars.1" (perhaps another SVNkit version too). Problem exists with SVNkit 1.8.11 and Native HL 1.8.14

Answer (score 6):

I have the same troubles with Subversive and Eclipse Mars.
The solution is in that page :
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=485622

If you have the last subversive version (3.0.3), you have to downgrade to 3.0.2.

You can find this version here : https://eclipse.org/subversive/latest-releases.php

Comment: I have found only Subversive SVN Team Provider v 3.0.1. This Version works too with only compatible Svn Connector SVNKit 1.8.11

Comment: Seems like this bug appears again in Version 4.0.3. I do not have this issue in Version 4.0.2. See also latest comments (starting with comment 10) in the bug ticket.

Answer (score 1):

Bug fixed in Version 3.0.4

[check bug ticket](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=485622)

Comment: A very similar error still occurrs for me using "Latest from Repository" and "Revision of URL..." commands

Comment: @Kawu I've checked both and they work for me using the 3.0.4 team provider version and the SVNKit 1.8.11 connector under windows with eclipse 4.5.2

Comment: @Kawu did you find a solution ? I too have this problem with 3.0.4 team provider and eclipse 4.5

Comment: For me, "Base from Working Copy" works and this is what I need 98% of the time. Other than that, compare with "Revision or URL..." shows the error dialog but shows the compare after closing the error dialog. Might not hold true for you though.